# How to add data via directories for training images

Tags: python, git, numpy, keras

I have been going through git repository by flyyufelix "https://github.com/flyyufelix/cnn_finetune" to fine tune an inception v3 network I want to train network to detect a disease so I have 2 set of images one with disease and without disease.
The git says X_train, Y_train, X_valid, Y_valid = load_data() he loads the cifar dataset ,The git asks us to create our own load_data() function.The author has the code as below

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras import backend as K
from keras.utils import np_utils

nb_train_samples = 3000 # 3000 training samples
nb_valid_samples = 100 # 100 validation samples
num_classes = 10

def load_cifar10_data(img_rows, img_cols):

    # Load cifar10 training and validation sets
    (X_train, Y_train), (X_valid, Y_valid) = cifar10.load_data()

    # Resize trainging images
    if K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th':
        X_train = np.array([cv2.resize(img.transpose(1,2,0), (img_rows,img_cols)).transpose(2,0,1) for img in X_train[:nb_train_samples,:,:,:]])
        X_valid = np.array([cv2.resize(img.transpose(1,2,0), (img_rows,img_cols)).transpose(2,0,1) for img in X_valid[:nb_valid_samples,:,:,:]])
    else:
        X_train = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (img_rows,img_cols)) for img in X_train[:nb_train_samples,:,:,:]])
        X_valid = np.array([cv2.resize(img, (img_rows,img_cols)) for img in X_valid[:nb_valid_samples,:,:,:]])

    # Transform targets to keras compatible format
    Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_train[:nb_train_samples], num_classes)
    Y_valid = np_utils.to_categorical(Y_valid[:nb_valid_samples],num_classes)
return X_train, Y_train, X_valid, Y_valid
```

can i know how to generate a function which loads
 data X_train, Y_train, X_valid, Y_valid = load_data() when i have directries in pc

Comment: keras `ImageDataGenerator` has `flow_from_directory` method that should work for your usecase: https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/

Comment: How will I be able to add labels to Y_train and Y_valid, I have two folders @filippo a folder containing images with a disease and folder containing images free from disease.I know i have to make it into one hot encoding format by doing like this Y = np_utils.to_categorical(labels, num_classes).But i am confused how will you know say labels from first 100 should be diseased and next 200 is not diseased etc

Comment: see the other answers, you should be able to infer the labels from the directory structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Keras'](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/) `ImageDataGenerator()` class and call `flow_from_directory()` on it. The labels will be automatically inferred from the directory names. So if you have a directory titled "disease," then Keras would infer that all images within that directory are labeled as "disease," and the same thing would be true for another directory titled "no disease," for example.

I demonstrate how to prepare image data for training a CNN in Keras in [this video](https://youtu.be/LhEMXbjGV_4). The first half of the video is about image organization on disk, and then the second half goes through the process described above.

Comment: @ blackHoleDetector I went through the tutorials and i have another doubt involving vgg16 the link is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111317/error-while-running-keras-vgg16-for-small-data-fine-tuning

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial once and all your doubts will get cleared. 
https://blog.keras.io/building-powerful-image-classification-models-using-very-little-data.html